# What is a Permutation of a Typing Environment?

Tags: permutations, type-theory

In *Types and Programming Languages* by Pierce the author talks about how permuting a typing environment does not affect bindings from variables to types. Specifically he states:

> The first structural lemma tells us that we may permute the elements of a context, as convenient, without changing the set of typing statements that can be derived under it.

He then presents the following lemma:

Lemma[Permutation]: If Γ ⊢ t : T and ∆ is a permutation of Γ, then ∆ ⊢ t : T. Moreover, the latter derivation has the same depth as the former.

$\Gamma$ is a function mapping variables to types, or equivalently a set of pairs of variables and types. A permutation is depending on the definition either a tuple of elements from a given set or a mapping from that set to itself. So in either case a permutation $\Delta$ of a function $\Gamma$ is of a different type than $\Gamma$ itself. But then the Lemma makes little sense, as it treats $\Delta$ just like $\Gamma$ in regard to their type.

So I must be misunderstanding the author here, who unfortunately does not clarify what he means by *permutation*.

What *does* he mean by it then and how is it related to the above two definitions of permutation?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A context $\Gamma$ is not a set of pairs of variables and types, it is a *list* of pairs of variables and types. So $\Gamma := (x:A, y: B, z:C)$ is a context.

(Looking at Pierce's book, he uses the term sequence rather than list.)

$\Delta:= (z:C,y:B,x:A)$ is also a context, but since contexts are lists and not sets, it is a different context than $\Gamma.$ However, since it contains the same variables and types in a different order, $\Delta$ is a permutation of $\Gamma.$

This is what is meant by the terminology. The lemma then just says that contexts that are permutations of one another are effectively equivalent, as one might expect.

Comment: Okay, but why define contexts as a sequence in the first place rather than a function from variables to types?

Comment: @user3578468 Not very knowledgeable in type theory (so you might try to ask a new question or follow up with someone who is), but I can think of two reasons. One is that syntactic manipulation of sequences is more straightforward than for sets. The second is that although the order doesn’t usually matter, we want to allow for the possibility of systems where it does. Cf  https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Substructural_type_system